# How to get detailed VM Size information

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I would like to use the Python Azure SDK to find the VM Sizes that support Enhanced Networking as well as AVX-512. The method I've seen so far to query information about VM Sizes is ComputeManagementClient.virtual_machine_sizes.list(region). But, the information returned doesn't include whether Enhanced Networking is supported for each VM type, or whether AVX-512 is supported.

This is an example of what one entry of virtual_machine_sizes.list provides:

```
{'name': 'Standard_M208ms_v2', 'numberOfCores': 208, 'osDiskSizeInMB': 1047552, 'resourceDiskSizeInMB': 4194304, 'memoryInMB': 5836800, 'maxDataDiskCount': 64}
```

I found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list that perhaps the resource skus list will provide the info I'm looking for. But, I don't see a way to use that resource skus list function in the Python SDK.

I am using version 4.0.0 of Python's azure library. Installed it via:

```
pip3 install -Iv azure==4.0.0
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list azure vm resource sku with python, please refer to the following steps:

1. Create a service principal and assign Contributor role to the sp

```
az login
#create sp and assign Contributor role at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "your service principal name"
```

[image]

2. code

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

client_id = "sp appId"
secret = "sp password"
tenant = "sp tenant"
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = client_id,
        secret = secret,
        tenant = tenant
)

Subscription_Id = ''
compute_client =ComputeManagementClient(credentials,Subscription_Id)
resource_group_name='Networking-WebApp-AppGW-V1-E2ESSL'
virtual_machine_scale_set_name='VMSS'
results = compute_client.resource_skus.list(raw=True)
resourceSkusList = [result.as_dict() for result in results]
r=json.dumps(resourceSkusList)
print(r)
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_09_01.operations.resourceskusoperations?view=azure-python).

Comment: This was useful in understanding how to exercise the resource SKU API via the Python SDK, and was also useful in being able to check the data returned by the resource SKU API. Thank you!

But, it didn't meet the goal I have in this post of programmatically being able to query the Azure API via the Python Azure SDK to determine which VM types support enhanced networking or AVX-512.

Comment: @Scott The resource SKU API now just  support filtering by region. And if you want to use it, we need to set api version above `2019-04-01`.  So if you check some information, you need to implement it by ourselves after getting the result.For example  Regarding how to check if the vm supports Enhanced Networking, we can use the value `AcceleratedNetworkingEnabled` in `capabilities`.

Comment: @Scott But we have no way check if the VM support  AVX-512 with the api. The api just returns some information about the number of vCPUs, data disks, and NICs,storage throughput and network bandwidth