# Azure REST API retrieve GPU memory size

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

I am trying to make a table with all of the GPU enabled Azure VM SKUs, including all the corresponding VM stats (vCPU, RAM, GPU sizes, etc.), and I decided to use the Azure Rest API to build it for me.  I'm using this API to get the information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resource-skus/list?tabs=HTTP

Unfortunately, I only get back the GPU **count**, not the GPU **memory size**.  Is there a way to get the GPU memory size from the Azure Rest APIs? Or is there another programmatic lookup available to take the VM family and look up the GPU type?  I could then build a separate table and do the calculations myself.

Here is a sample output from calling the API:
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2021-07-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2021-07-01)

```
{

    "locations": [

        "eastus"

    ],

    "capabilities": [

        {

            "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",

            "value": "389120"

        },

        {

            "name": "OSVhdSizeMB",

            "value": "1047552"

        },

        {

            "name": "vCPUs",

            "value": "6"

        },

...

        {

            "name": "GPUs",

            "value": "1"

        },

        {

            "name": "vCPUsPerCore",

            "value": "1"

        }

    ],

    "locationInfo": [

        {

            "location": "eastus",

            "zones": [

                "useast-AZ01",

                "useast-AZ02"

            ]

        }

    ],

    "name": "Standard_NV6",

    "tier": "Standard",

    "size": "NV6",

    "family": "standardNVFamily"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dictionnaire of ressource / gpu size either manually from [the azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu) :

```
gpu_size = {"Standard_NC6s_v3":"16Go" , "Standard_NC12s_v3":"32Go" , "Standard_NC24s_v3":"64Go" , "Standard_NC24rs_v3*":"64Go"}
```

or using python like it's done in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63333168/12986294).

and after getting the dict you must match between the sku's and add the data to the main json.

Comment: I would prefer to not have to maintain information that could change.  I would prefer to have an API that I can call to give me the information, in case I miss a SKU or the SKU changes.